# Do we need to add RegistrySearch element in WiX 3.11 installer if checking the existence of .NET Framework version

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

In the older versions of WiX I've seen the following xml fragment for checking the existence of `.NET Framework 4.0` and aborting the installation if the `.NET Framework` is not present on the operation system. But in this official documentation on [How To: Check for .NET Framework Versions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html) has not mentioned any `RegistrySearch` element. **Question**: Is RegistrySearch element still needs to be included here or it's not needed in the latest version **3.11** of `WiX`?

```
<Property Id="VSTORUNTIMEREDIST">
  <RegistrySearch
    Id="VSTORuntimeRedist"
    Root="HKLM"
    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R"
    Name="Version"
    Type="raw" />
</Property>
<Condition
  Message="The Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime is not installed. Please download and install from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20479.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR VSTORUNTIMEREDIST>="10.0.30319"]]>
</Condition>

<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]>
</Condition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code RegistrySearch relates to The Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime and not to .NET Framework.  It is not needed for testing the presence of .NET.